# Delay calling an API in a loop

Tags: angularjs

I want to call an API every 2 seconds in a loop. How can i achieve this?

```
var letterArray = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
for (var j = 0; j < letterArray.length; j++) {
    $timeout(callApi(letterArray[j]), 2000);
}

function callApi(searchInput) {
    var request = {
        // 
        url: 'https://someApi/search?name=' + searchInput,
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'abc'
        }
    };
    $http(request).then(onComplete, onError);
}
```

Comment: What is not working about your code?

Comment: the $timeout doesn't work. There's no delay in calling the function.

Comment: The interval seems to work. But I can't pass in any variable. The function doesn't have visibility on `letterArray[j]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use $interval instead of $timeout and remove that loop, use a variable to keep track. Remember to dispose and cancel interval when scope disposes.

```
var letterArray = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

var inr = $interval(function(){
    var search = letterArray.shift();
    if(!search && inr) {
          $interval.cancel(inr);
          inr = null;
    }
    callApi(search);
}, 2000);

function callApi(searchInput) {
    var request = {
        // 
        url: 'https://someApi/search?name=' + searchInput,
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'abc'
        }
    };
    $http(request).then(onComplete, onError);
}
```

on that note, you may also want to cancel interval on exception with api or any scope dispose etc.

Comment: Can't remove the loop. I need to call the same api with multiple search criteria.

Comment: So let me get this straight, you want to call the api with some search criteria off an array every 2 seconds ? You can sitll use $interval for that since, you're not really doing anything with results so no need for a chain. Use some var as counter and cancle the interval once you're done. Youre not really achieving anything at all by doing this, except maybe dont send all  quests at onces. If you're trying to achieve more than this, you may need to look at promises and chain/sequence promises.

Comment: I am doing something with the result but the api throws an error if i send too many requests at once so I need a delay between each API call.

Comment: The proper way to do this is to use chained promises with timeout; however, the $interval solution can still work here. Looks like someone posted an reference to a solution using $interval in comment.

Comment: How can I pass an argument in the function using `$interval`.